# Не удается загрузить страницу через прокси

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Использую cURL и прокси SOCKS5.
Делаю так:

```
     $options = array(

        CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_SOCKS5,
        CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => $proxy_user.':'.$proxy_pass,
        CURLOPT_PROXY => $proxyIP.':'.$proxyPort,


        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,    
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36", 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, 
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies/'.md5($login).'.txt',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies/'.md5($login).'.txt',
    );

    $ch      = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

> Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:000a:0. (2)

С чем это может быть связано? Прокси рабочая на 100%.

Comment: пропробуйте через curl подключиться, есть подозрения, что проблемы не на стороне php а самого сокета

Comment: @ВадимАлександру без прокси подключается

Comment: С прокси через обычный курл из командной строки, к примеру curl -x socks5://[user:password@]proxyhost[:port]/ url
curl --socks5 192.168.1.254:3099 https://google.com

Comment: Попробуй поменять CURLPROXY_SOCKS5 на CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME